# Grouped histogram based on range in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I have a dataset in this format and I would like to make a grouped histogram plot and with ranges i.e. `10-20, 20-30, ..., 90-100`.

```
   group weight
1  A     54
2  A     55
3  B     52
4  B     53
5  C     60
```

I have tried the following to generate the histogram, but not sure how to make the weight ranges in the X-axis.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = weight)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(color = gp), fill = "white",
                 position = "identity", bins = 30) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "blue", 'green'))
```

[image]

I actually need a histogram like the following

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a bar chart, not a histogram. Here is an approach to reproduce it:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(weight_class = cut(weight,
                            breaks = seq(20, 60, by = 10))) %>%
  ggplot() +
    geom_bar(aes(x = weight_class, fill = group), position = "dodge") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green"))
```

Comment: It gives the following error `Error in cut(weight, breaks = seq(20, 60, by = 10)) : object 'weight' not found`

Comment: Does your `df`  object have a `weight` column?

Comment: Yes, it does have a `weight` column. I am executing the syntax on R studio like this `df <- mutate(weight_class = cut(weight, breaks = seq(20, 60, by = 10)))`

Comment: That will not work. But you can call `df <- mutate(df, weight_class = cut(weight, breaks = seq(20, 60, by = 10)))`

Comment: Thanks !! It looks good now when I executed the following `df<- mutate(df, weight_class = cut(weight, breaks = seq(20, 70, by = 10))) ` and 
`ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(x = weight_class, fill = gp), position = "dodge") + scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green"))`