# grouped bar chart with age range within each group

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouped-bar-chart

I have a list of people and their group and age in a table similar to the example below. I would like to draw a grouped bar chart based on age range.

```
  Group Age
1  G1    29
2  G2    25
3  G3    55
4  G2    33
5  G1    70
6  G3    80
```

I tried the following syntax given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67826276/grouped-histogram-based-on-range-in-r), but not sure how to divide the plots into three groups and age ranges within each group

```
df<- mutate(df, age_class = cut(Age, breaks = seq(20, 80, by = 10)))  
ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes(x = age_class, fill = Group), position = "dodge") + scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a bar plot that counts the number of times each group appears in each age range (correct me if not, but this is what your attempt tried), you can do the following:

```
library(tidyverse)
# Reproducing your data
df1 <- tibble(
  Group = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G1", "G2", "G3"),
  Age = c(29, 25, 55, 33, 70, 80)
)
```

One of the problems with your current attempt is that you're trying to direct `cut` towards a column called `weight`, but there is no such column present in your data. To fix this, you can correctly refer to your column `Age` as below:

```
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(Age_class = cut(Age, breaks = seq(20, 80, by = 10)))
```

Then, plot like so:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x = Age_class, fill = Group)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green"))
```

This gives the count of each age range within each group - all the counts are 1 in your reproducible example, so the output graph looks like this:

[image: ggplot bar chart of count in each group, per age class]

Comment: Thanks  !! I am just wondering what changes need to be done if I want my x-axis to have three separate groups i.e. G1, G2, and G3 and within each group, there are ranges (i.e 20-30, 30-40 rtc.) as you plotted.

Comment: I think I got it now. This works for me `ggplot(df1, aes(x = Group, fill = age_class)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "green", "orange", "yellow"))`

Comment: @BeginneR great, that's what I'd have suggested - no worries!

Comment: Thanks a lot !! I am just trying for the percentage (instead of count) of each range within each group. Is there any fix to this?

Comment: @BeginneR you'd probably have to calculate the proportion of "Group" occurences within each `Age_class` using `mutate`, and then plot this on the y axis of your graph. Perhaps you could post a new question asking this, so that the answer is more visible? I'm happy to give it a go.